# Getting highest extensions value in unix script

Tags: unix

I need to create new files with extensions like: file.1, file.2, file.3 and then check if files with certain numbers exist and create file.(n+1) where n is number of highest, existing file. I was trying to get extensions using basename but it doesn't want to get couple of files

```
file=`basename $file.*`
ext=${file##*.}
```

It only works when I input whole file name like `$file.3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the filenames are guaranteed not to have newline characters in them, you can, for example, use standard unix text processing tools:

```
printf '%s\n' file.* | #full list
sed 's/.*\.//' | #extensions
grep '^[0-9][0-9]*$' | #numerical extensions
awk '{ if($0>m) m=$0} END{ print m }' #get maximum
```

Comment: The only thing this script returns is `txt`, and there are other files in this folder: file. file.1 file.2 file.3 file.txt. edit: Oh, my bad. the txt was also taken account and I only need numbers.

Comment: @codddeer123 Added a filter for numbers only. You need to phrase your questions more clearly.

Comment: I don't know why but unfortunatelly it doesn't work for me. `➜  dir ls 
file.1    file.2    file.3    script.sh
➜  dir ./script.sh

` It doesn't return anything.

Comment: @codddeer123 Sorry, that added grep filter was wrong. Plain grep doesn't have `+`. You either need -P or `^[0-9][0-9]*$` with classical grep. It should work now.

Comment: @PSkocik - actually it's not `-P` (which enables Perl-style RE in GNU grep) but ERE which is `egrep` or `grep -E`. Of course, you can use `-P` if you have it, but `egrep` is more portable and just as functional for a case like this.

Comment: @ghoti Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on this.

You can do this entirely in standard awk.

```
$ awk '{ext=FILENAME;sub(/.*\./,"",ext)} ext>n&&ext~/^[0-9]+$/{n=ext}{nextfile} END {print n}' *.*
```

Broken out for easier reading:

```
$ awk '
  {
    # Capture the extension...
    ext=FILENAME
    sub(/.*\./,"",ext)
  }

  # Then, if we have a numeric extension that is bigger than "n"...
  ext > n && ext ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {
    # let "n" be that extension.
    n=ext
  }

  {
    # We aren't actually interested in the contents of this file, so move on.
    nextfile
  }

  # No more files? Print our result.
  END {print n}
' *.*
```

The idea here is that we'll step through the list of filenames and let awk do ALL the processing to capture and "sort" the extensions. (We're not really sorting, we're just recording the highest number as we pass through the files.)

There are a few provisos with this solution:

1. This only works if all the files have a non-zero length. Technically awk conditions are being compared on "lines of the file", so if there are no lines, awk will pass right by that file.
2. You don't really need to use the `ext` variable, you can modify `FILENAME` directly. I included it for improved readability.
3. The `nextfile` command is fairly standard, but not universal. If you have a very old machine, or are running an esoteric variety of unix, `nextfile` may not be included. (I don't expect this to be a problem.)

---

Another alternative, which might be easier for you, would be to implement the same logic directly in POSIX shell:

```
$ n=0; for f in *.*; do ext=${f##*.}; if expr "$ext" : '[0-9][0-9]*$' >/dev/null && [ "$ext" -gt "$n" ]; then n="$ext"; fi; done; echo "$n"
```

Or, again broken out for easier reading (or scripting):

```
n=0
for f in *.*; do
  ext=${f##*.}
  if expr "$ext" : '[0-9][0-9]*$' >/dev/null && [ "$ext" -gt "$n" ]; then
    n="$ext"
  fi
done
echo "$n"
```

This steps through all files using a for loop, captures the extension, makes sure it's numeric, determines whether it's greater than "n" and records if it it is, then prints its result.

It requires no pipes and no external tools except `expr`, which is a POSIX.1 tool available on every system.

One proviso for this solution is that if you have NO files with extensions (i.e. `*.*` returns no files), this script will erroneously report that the highest numbered extension is `0`. You can of course handle that easily enough, but I thought I should mention it.

Comment: and is there any way to get the result as a variable so that I can use it later? Like echo $n and to get the highest number?

Comment: If you want to store the result of this awk script in a shell variable, you have a number of options. One nice one if you want to use this in multiple parts of your script would be to put the awk script into a shell function (`highest() { awk '...' }`), and then refer to it using command substitution, i.e. `n=$(highest)`. Or you could just put the awk script into the command substitution directly.

Comment: @codddeer123 - I've added a shell-only implementation of the same logic as I demonstrated in awk, which has the benefit of a "leftover" variable which is the datum you're looking for. Enjoy.

Comment: Hmm, the output is quite weird. `➜  dir ls
file.1    file.2    file.3    script.sh
➜  dir ./script.sh
1
1
1
0
3`

Comment: @codddeer123 - ah, oops, I left some debugging code in the one-liner version. I've removed it now. Sorry about that, please try again.

Comment: Exactly the same output in one-liner version and the extended one. I wonder if there is any way to make it even simpler using while loop to check `file.$n` and then add until it's bigger then `$n`. Something like: `ext=${f##*.}
while [[ "$ext" -gt "$n" ]]; do
 a=$"n"
done
sed -e 's/'$input1'/'$input2'/g' "$file" > "file.${n}"`

Comment: Did you include the `> /dev/null` after `expr`?

Comment: Ok, now it works but there is another problem. If I try to add +1 using expr: `x= "expr $n + 1"` output is `abc`

Comment: Ok, I have finally made it to work like I wanted but there is one final question: expr a : b returns 1 if a=b and 0 when a != b. So as I can see you are comparing if expr is something between 0 and 9, and then making simple sort here: `[ "$ext" -gt "$n" ]`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers, I've came up with quite similar and a bit simpler idea which I'd like to present it:

```
for i in file.*; do
  #reading the extensions
  ext=${i##*.}
  if [ "$ext" -gt "$n" ];
    then
        #increasing n
        n=$((n+1))
  fi
done
```

then if we want to get number exceeding n by one

```
until [[ $a -gt "$n" ]]; do
    a=$((a+1))
done
```

and finally a is one number bigger then number of file extensions. So if there are three files: file.1 file.2 file.3 the returned value will be 4.